Is nested parameters allowed in CircleCI?
I need some clarification regarding parameter types in CircleCI.I was going through the CircleCI documentation, which states the following:
The parameter types supported by orbs are:

string
boolean
integer
enum
executor
steps
environment variable name
The parameter types supported by pipeline parameters are:

string
boolean
integer
enum

Given this information, can anyone confirm that nested parameters are indeed not supported? I need to define a parameter split-type(string type) inside another parameter use-split(boolean type). How can I handle this scenario correctly within CircleCI's constraints?
